# Select list columns that match TRUE

Tags: r

I have two lists as a result of some processing. The objective is to grab only those columns from the lists that is `TRUE` in the second list.

Here's some example data:

```
> first_try
[[1]]
      X1     X2     X3  X4
1 status income verbal sex

[[2]]
      X1     X2     X3     X4
1 status income verbal    sex
2 income verbal    sex status

> second_try
$`1`
     X1    X2    X3   X4
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE

$`2`
     X1    X2   X3   X4
2 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

So for the `first` list we only select `X4` from `[[1]]` because it has a value `TRUE` in `second` at `[[1]]`, and from list `[[2]]` we only select `X3,X4` because it has the value `TRUE`, and so forth.

I thought that I could somehow merge the two lists and try getting it that way, but I was having difficulties getting this to work.

something that I tried:

```
first <- list()
second <- list()
for(i in 1:length(second_try)){
  second[[i]]<-second_try[[i]] %>% pivot_longer(-c())
  first[[i]]<-first_try[[i]] %>% pivot_longer(-c()) 
}

first %>% mapply(function(x, y)inner_join(x, y, by='name'), second, .)
```

Expected output:

```
> first_try
[[1]]
 X4
sex

[[2]]
  X3       X4
verbal     sex
 sex      status
```

Reproducible code:

```
first_try<-list(structure(list(X1 = "status", X2 = "income", X3 = "verbal", 
    X4 = "sex"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
    X1 = c("status", "income"), X2 = c("income", "verbal"), X3 = c("verbal", 
    "sex"), X4 = c("sex", "status")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"))
second_try<-list(`1` = structure(list(X1 = FALSE, X2 = FALSE, X3 = FALSE, 
    X4 = TRUE), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(
    X1 = FALSE, X2 = FALSE, X3 = TRUE, X4 = TRUE), row.names = 2L, class = "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a single line of code in base R. Use `Map` to subset each member of `first_try` by the `unlist`ed member at the equivalent position of `second_try`.

```r
Map(function(a, b) a[unlist(b)], first_try, second_try)
#> [[1]]
#>    X4
#> 1 sex
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>       X3     X4
#> 1 verbal    sex
#> 2    sex status
```

Comment: Wow! why does this work exactly? the `unlist` part slightly throws me off here

Comment: Because each member of `second_try` has a single row, `unlist` turns it into a vector which can be used to subset the columns of `first_try`

Comment: Ah I see, and if second try had multiple rows for each list, would this method continue to work? Although, I cannot think of a reason why I would need multiple rows with `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: No, because then you wouldn't be selecting columns, but cells. And then the result would no longer be a rectangular data frame, since some columns might end up longer than others

Comment: Or using tidyverse `map2(first_try, second_try, ~ .x %>% select(which(unlist(.y))))`